# How to use jQuery UI tabs to load external div via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, tabs

I'm using the Jquery UI tabs functionality to load content via ajax. I'd like to load a particular div in the ajax call, not the entire page. Is this possible without using jQuery's load()?

As you can see from the code, it's a stock standard basic jQuery tabs implementation, but I want a particular div rather than the full page.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="tab-1">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="tab-2">Tab Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.domain.com #target">Ajax tab</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1>Tab one content</div>
    <div id="tab-2>Tab two content</div>
</div>
```

And the inline script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();    
    });
</script>
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Are you saying you need to load some content inside a tab through ajax, but not the entire content of the tab? Also, why is the tab's load() event is not an option?

Comment: I need to load content from a remote page via ajax, but not the entire page, only a single div ie #content. I'd like to do it without using load() if possible, but am not opposed to doing so. I'm not entirely sure if ajax is the best solution as I need a fallback for users with javascript turned off, so I might go back to working serverside instead

Comment: So you don't want to use load() to make ajax call because your users may have javascript turned off? In this case you probably shouldn't use jQuery UI too, buecause the Tabs libaray uses load() to load remote content. Like you say, you're probably better off with server side pages if having javascript turned off matters to you.

Comment: yeah, it kind of defeats using jQuery at all if users might have js turned off...

Answer (score 0):

Nathan.

Yes, it is possible. Use jQuery ajax "load" function. Example:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

For your 3rd tab you should manually load content via ajax call, also you can define selector which exactly part of loaded page you need. So, create 3rd tab as via general way, load page content for 3rd tab and create tabs. Or you can dynamically load 3rd tab's content when the user clicks on tab.

More information here: http://api.jquery.com/load/, please see paragraph "Loading Page Fragments".